# How to partition a square into successive halves

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I am teaching the idea of infinite geometric series to high school students,  looking for hints to create the diagram below using Mathematica.  (I don't need the labels).   I can do it manually, but hoping for a "manipulate" kind of solution to illustrate the process.
[image: divided square]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1/32 and 1/128 being at the "bottom" of the larger rectangles enclosing them instead of at the "top" complicates things. Is this necessary?

Comment: No,  the actual  layout doesn't really matter, as long as it is visibly being divided up 1/2, 1/2 of the half, etc.

Answer (score 10):

A starting point:

```
With[{n = 4}, 
     Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[97] @@ #2, #1} &, 
                         Append[Riffle[
                         Table[Rectangle[{1 - 2^(1 - k), 0}, {1 - 2^-k, 2^-k}], {k, n}], 
                         Table[Rectangle[{1 - 2^(1 - k), 2^-k}, {1, 2^(1 - k)}], {k, n}]],
                         Rectangle[{1 - 2^-n, 0}, {1, 2^-n}]]], 
              PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image: halved rectangles]

Here's something with labels. I'll let someone else work out how to properly size the text:

```
With[{n = 4}, 
     Graphics[MapIndexed[{{ColorData[97] @@ #2, #1},
                          {White, Text[Style[ToString[1/2^First[#2], InputForm], Tiny], 
                                       Mean[List @@ #1]]}} &, 
                         Append[Riffle[
                         Table[Rectangle[{1 - 2^(1 - k), 2^-k}, {1, 2^(1 - k)}], {k, n}], 
                         Table[Rectangle[{1 - 2^(1 - k), 0}, {1 - 2^-k, 2^-k}], {k, n}]], 
                         Rectangle[{1 - 2^-n, 0}, {1, 2^-n}]]], 
              PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]
```

Comment: +1 Replace `With` by `Manipulate`, e.g., `Manipulate[Graphics[ ... ], {{n, 4}, Range[7], ControlType -> SetterBar}]`

Comment: @Tom, since you're discussing geometric series with kids, an interesting exercise is how I derived the coordinate expressions within the `Rectangle[]` objects.

Comment: I'm working online, so sadly, little discussion!   This is mostly to help illustrate the ideas,  and your answer really helped with that!

Answer (score 6):

Using `ArrayPad` + `Fold` + `Nest` + `MatrixPlot`

```
ClearAll[padMat]
padMat = Fold[ArrayPad[#, RotateLeft[{{0}, {Length @ #, 0}}, #2 - 1], 1 + Max @ #] &, 
  #, {1, 2}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
With[{n = 6}, MatrixPlot[Nest[padMat, {{1}}, n] /. x_Integer :> ColorData[97][x], 
 ImageSize -> 600, Frame -> False, Mesh -> All]]
```

[image]

```
Grid @ Partition[#, 3] & @ Table[
 MatrixPlot[Nest[padMat, {{1}}, n] /. x_Integer :> ColorData[97][x], 
   ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> False, Mesh -> All], {n, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Using `Fold` + `ArrayPad` only:

```
ClearAll[paddedMat]
paddedMat[n_] := Fold[
  ArrayPad[#, RotateLeft[{{0}, {Length @ #, 0}}, #2 - 1], 1 + Max @ #] &, 
  {{1}}, Mod[Range[n], 2, 1]];
```

***Example:***

```
With[{n = 10}, MatrixPlot[paddedMat[n] /. x_Integer :> ColorData[97][x], 
  ImageSize -> 700, Frame -> False, Mesh -> All]]
```

[image]

We can add labels using `Epilog`:

```
With[{n = 8}, 
 MatrixPlot[paddedMat[n] /. x_Integer :> ColorData[97][x], 
  Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 700, Frame -> False, 
  Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[Style[2^-Min[#2[[1]], n], 
       Max[8, 72/Min[#2[[1]], n - 1]]], #] &, 
    Reverse[{# - 1, 2^(Floor[n/2]) - #2} + 1/2 & @@@ 
     (Reverse @ Mean[Position[paddedMat[n], #]] & /@ Range[1 + n])]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We can also use affine transformations of the unit rectangle to get the desired picture:

```
ClearAll[rectangleCoords]
rectangleCoords[n_] :=  Module[{mod = Mod[Range[0, n - 2], 2], 
   sy = 2^Floor[Range[0, n - 2]/2], rcoords = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}}, 
  Through[(Reverse @ Prepend[Identity][AffineTransform[{{{#, 0}, {0, #2}}, {##3}}] & @@@
    (Transpose[{(1 + mod) #, #, (1 - mod) #, mod #}] & @ sy)])@ rcoords]]
```

***Examples:***

```
With[{n = 9}, 
 Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[97]@#2[[1]], Rectangle @@ #, Black, 
     Text[Style[2^-Min[#2[[1]], n - 1], Max[8, 72/Min[#2[[1]], n - 1]]], Mean@#]} &, 
   rectangleCoords[n]], ImageSize -> 1 -> 40]]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[97]@#2[[1]], Rectangle @@ #, Black, 
  Text[Style[2^-Min[#2[[1]], n - 1], 
       Max[8, 72/Max[1, Min[#2[[1]], n - 1]]]], Mean @ #]} &, rectangleCoords[n]], 
  ImageSize -> 800], 
 {{n, 7}, Range[11], SetterBar}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer, but I don't understand why sometimes, as seen in the last screen shot,  you get a "rectangle" instead of the square.   Otherwise,  the "perfect" answer!  Seems to have an error for "even" values of n...?

Comment: @TomDeVries, in this implementation, the parameter `n`  represents the number of rectangles. For odd `n` we get a square; for  even `n` we get  a rectangle instead of a square.

Answer (score 2):

We can also recursively divide  the bottom-right rectangle into three rectangles as follows:

```
ClearAll[threerects, step, rectlist]
threerects = # /. Rectangle[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}] :> 
     {Rectangle[{a, (b + d)/2}, {c, d}], 
      Rectangle[{a, b}, {a + c, b + d}/2], 
      Rectangle[{(a + c)/2, b}, {c, (b + d)/2}]} &;

Graphics[MapIndexed[{{Red, Green, Blue}[[#2[[1]]]], #} &, 
  threerects[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]]]]
```

[image]

We use `threerects` recursively to replace the last rectangle in a list of rectangles starting with a list containing only the unit rectangle:

```
ClearAll[step, rectlist]

step = # /. {a___Rectangle, b_Rectangle} :> Flatten[{a, threerects @ b}] &;

rectlist[n_] := Nest[step, {Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, n]
```

***Examples:***

```
frames = Table[Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[97]@#2[[1]], #} &, rectlist @ n], 
    ImageSize -> 360], {n, 0, 7}];

Export["rectangles.gif", frames, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity, 
 DisplayAllSteps -> True, 
 "DisplayDurations" -> Table[1., Length[frames]]]
```

[image]

```
With[{n = 4}, Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[97] @ #2[[1]], #, Black, 
     Text[Style[2^(-Min[#2[[1]], 2 n]), Max[8, 72/Max[1, Min[#2[[1]], 2 n]]]], 
        RegionCentroid @ #]} &, rectlist @ n],
   ImageSize -> 600]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
With[{n=4},
 Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData["Rainbow",(Tr@#2-1)/2/n],Rectangle@@#, 
  Text[Style[2^-Tr@#2,White,12],Mean@#]}&,
   Join@@ReIm@NestList[(#+1)/2&,{{I,2+2I},{0,1+I}}/2,n-1]]]]
```

[image]